# How do I Add a UITextView on top of AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, uitextview, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an app that plays audio tracks.  Previously, when I used MPMoviePlayerViewController, I was able to put a UITextView on top of the player to display lyrics. Since switching to AVPlayerViewController, the only way I can see that I can add text on top of the view is to use the contentOverlayView - but the text window is static and will not scroll as it did on the MPMoviePlayerViewController.

The only other way have found to achieve this is to add the UITextView as a subview to the window, but then it appears beneath the AVPlayer, and I have been unable to move it to be on top of the player. I have already tried using bringSubviewToFront and that does not work.

This is how I add the TextView:

```
   textViewAZ = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        textViewAZ.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, self.view.frame.size.width-80, self.view.frame.size.height-150);
    }
    else
    {
        textViewAZ.frame = CGRectMake(150, 140, self.view.frame.size.width-80,self.view.frame.size.height-100);
    }
textViewAZ.text = playingLyrics;
textViewAZ.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textViewAZ.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textViewAZ.scrollEnabled = YES;
UIWindow *currentWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[currentWindow addSubview:textViewAZ];
[currentWindow bringSubviewToFront:textViewAZ];
```

Does anyone know of a way to put a scrollable text view on top of the AVPlayerViewController?

Comment: Can you show how you set up your textView as a [example]? Did you enable `isScrollEnabled` ?

Comment: I have added the code to add the TextView above.  I am able to get the TextView to appear only behind the AVPlayer, not on top of it.  It appears that the only way to get the text on top of the player is to use the player's contentOverlayView property, but that doesn't have a scroll option.

Comment: `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  Make sure to also set `[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`